Image display above cell issue how to solve issue using iTextsharp?
I work on ASP.NET; I export a grid view to PDF and I am successful with that.
The issue happens when I add an image / logo to the PDF; it gets displayed above logoCell - not inside the cell, as it should be.
I create cell for logo it is exist on top and I need to add logo to display inside it but issue it display outside cell.
How to solve this issue?
This is the code I try so far:
[WebMethod]
public byte[] ExportGridViewToPdf(string[][] gridData, string[] columnNames)
{
    try
    {
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, ms);

        document.Open();

        var tahomaFontFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Fonts), "Tahoma.ttf");
        var tahomaBaseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(tahomaFontFile, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
        var tahomaFont = new Font(tahomaBaseFont, 8, Font.NORMAL);
                
        var table = new PdfPTable(columnNames.Length)
                {
                    RunDirection = PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL
                }; 
        table.WidthPercentage = 100;
               
        string imagePath2 = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, "assets", "images", "logo_kw.png");

        // Load the image from file
        System.Drawing.Image logoImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(imagePath2);

        iTextSharp.text.Image itextImage = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(logoImage, BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY);
                
        PdfPCell logoCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(new Chunk(itextImage, 0, 0)))
                {
                    Colspan = columnNames.Length, // Span across all columns
                    BackgroundColor = new BaseColor(System.Drawing.Color.LightGray),
                    HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER,
                    VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER,
                    PaddingBottom=Element.ALIGN_BOTTOM,
                    //HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER,
                    FixedHeight = 50f // Set the desired height for the logo cell
                };
        table.AddCell(logoCell);

        string titleText = "Price List for Customers";
        var titleCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(titleText, tahomaFont))
                {
                    Colspan = columnNames.Length, // Span across all columns
                    BackgroundColor = new BaseColor(System.Drawing.Color.LightGray),
                    HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER,
                    FixedHeight = 30f // Set the desired height (adjust as needed)
                };
        table.AddCell(titleCell);
             
        foreach (var columnName in columnNames)
        {
            var cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(columnName, tahomaFont));
            cell.BackgroundColor = new BaseColor(System.Drawing.Color.LightGray);
            cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
            table.AddCell(cell);
        }

        // Add the data rows
        foreach (var row in gridData)
        {
            var cells = new PdfPCell[columnNames.Length];

            for (int i = 0; i < columnNames.Length; i++)
            {
                cells[i] = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(row[i], tahomaFont));
                cells[i].FixedHeight = 25f;
                table.AddCell(cells[i]); // Add each cell individually
            }
        }

        document.Add(table);

        document.Close();
        writer.Close();

        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

        return ms.ToArray();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("Error exporting GridView to PDF: " + ex.Message);
    }
}

   

Screenshot with red mark display above cell 

Next time please tag it as iText/itextSharp as well then it popups in our rss feeds we use to track SO questions.
Also can you provide the itextSharp version you are using?
